# Scala - how to avoid closure?

Tags: scala, closures

How to avoid closure when passing a function as a parameter to a class constructor?

My class constructor accepts a function of type `() => Unit`. During the program working process, I want to access a key-value pair from a mutable map, that was not defined at the moment of creating the object with the constructor

```
val cats = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Cat]

class Trigger(period: Long, f: () => Unit) {

  //pseudocode:
  when period passes, f()

}

someWonderfulObject += new Trigger (1000, () => cats("Hershy").meow)

cats += ("Hershy" -> Cat())
```

and then, when the wonderful object triggers its triggers, I get the error that there is no key like "Hershy". I conclude that apparently, this is due to the `f` passed to the `Trigger` cons being closured in a state when there was no "Hershy".

My question is now - how to avoid Scala making use of closures here and instead look at the actual state of `cats`?

**UPDATE:**

The code for "when period passes" is this:

```
def update(tpf: Float) {
  timePassed += tpf
  if(timePassed > period) f()
}
```

The `tpf` value comes from above, so here all this seems ok.

**UPDATE:**

I have found the problem to be in another, totally irrelevant place, I have confused the containers of all this stuff. Howevr, thank you all, I have learned something from the answers.

Comment: Your cats is a `val` holding a ref to a mutable collection. A closure won't clone your object, the only thing it could theoretically do is copy the value of `cats` (a reference). But since `cats` is a `val`, in other words a constant, this cannot be any source of problem.

Comment: BTW, how can this compile: `("Hershy" -> Cat)`? `Cat` is a class, it's not a `Cat` itself. I guess it's just pseudocode -- it always confuses things when other people are trying to debug your code they have never seen.

Comment: oh, sorry, it meant to be Cat()

Comment: The behavior of your code is timing-sensitive and thread-unsafe. You are mutating the map and then reading it from another thread. There is no guarantee that the code that adds the map entry must execute before your time-trigger, and even if it does, there is still no guarantee the timer thread will observe the change. Whether this is your immediate problem is not clear.

Comment: Could you please show the code for `when period passes`. Note that if this blocks, the whole time will be spent during the `new Trigger` call, hence, your map-filling code will not even have been executed yet!

Comment: I'll just correct one thing here... a closure captures the state from its executing context. Like, for instance, the mutable `cats` map that is defined outside the function you are passing. So the behavior you want is possible _only_ with closures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Closures do no such thing (that would be quite hard to specify, have terrible performance, and make the whole thing useless). The closure may contains a reference to cats, or to the instance containing cats, not a copy.

This code works as expected :

```
val cats = collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()

class Trigger(name: String, f: () => Unit) {
  def fire = {
    println("Fire " + name)
    f()
  }
}

val trigger = new Trigger("calling Hershy", () => println(cats("Hershy")))
cats += "Hershy" -> "meow"
trigger.fire // prints Fire calling Hershy
```

The closure is not at fault, I suspect this is something that does not appear in your sample.

Comment: nice example, but never ever forget that cats "meow" ;-) you forgot that crucial bit, in addition to printing "Fire calling Hershy", it also prints "meow"; without the "meow" your answer would have not be the closures-in-a-nutshell example that it is...